# How to check condition inside map without putting a div

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to put a "col-sm-6" inside a row with checking a condition . But when null value is coming it is returning a blank div with ".col-sm-6" class, I need to hide that class when value is null.

```
<div className="row">
  {attribute.attributeValues.map((list, index) =>
     <div className="col-sm-6" >
        {list.isSelected === 1 ?
           <div className="style">
             <span><i className="fa fa-check"></i>{list.tag_value}</span>
           </div>:''
         }
     </div>
  )} 
</div>
```

this is giving results like:

like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">Some Value</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

But I want:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">Some Value</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">Some Value</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">Some Value</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) like

```
<div className="row">
  {attribute.attributeValues.map((list, index) => 
     <React.Fragment key={index}>
         {list.isSelected === 1 ?
           <div className="style">
             <span><i className="fa fa-check"></i>{list.tag_value}</span>
           </div>:''
         }
     </React.Fragment>
  )} 
</div>
```

According to the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)**:

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple
>   elements. `Fragments` let you group a list of children without adding
>   extra nodes to the DOM.

---

**Second method** to remove the wrapping `{}` in the ternary condition

```
<div className="row">
  {attribute.attributeValues.map((list, index) => 
     list.isSelected === 1 ?
           <div className="style">
             <span><i className="fa fa-check"></i>{list.tag_value}</span>
           </div>: null
   )} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need to use `filter` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) before the `map`. You can do something like:

`attribute.attributeValues.filter(list => list.tag_value).map(...`

That way, with `filter`, you return a new Array in which only items with a "real" `list.tag_value` value.

In JavaScript, everything without a "Value" is `False` ([JavaScript Booleans](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp)). That means that the `filter` above will filter out any `list.tag_value` equal to: `undefined`, `null`, empty String (`""`) or Number equal to `0`.